# Problems with Wordpress noConflict mode and Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

When assigning `(event)` my console starts to output this `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'ajaxSetup'` which I'm only guessing, is because for some reason jQuery is looking for the $ which was originally in the function call.

The script below works until the first `$` is called in the `.click(function(event){`

Is this a wordpress Ajax problem?

```
jQuery(".articleTitle a").click(function(event){

event.preventDefault();
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
var post_id = $(this).attr("href");
$("#fold-above").css('display','none');
$("#fold-above").fadeIn(300);
$("#fold-above").load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajaxpost/",{id:post_id});

return false;
});
```

Comment: replace `$` with `jQuery` just like you did for binding the click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In wordpress, use a noConflict wrapper to keep the value of `$`, otherwise it will be undefined:

```
jQuery(function($) { // wrap your code in this, and use the dollarsign inside

    $(".articleTitle a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var post_id = $(this).attr("href");

        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

        $("#fold-above").css('display','none')
                        .fadeIn(300)
                        .load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajaxpost/",{id:post_id});
    });

});
```

Comment: I know there's a big debate about the wordpress noConflict, but solutions like this keep it all flowing nicely. Thanks